# Force label background: url() In Internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-9

I have a Html/Css code that work fine in Chrome and firefox but in IE i can't show up the background for  my label

i have two class css one for active lable and other for no active.

Here is my Css Code:

```
.jqTransformDayRadioWrapper label {
    width: 31px !important;
    height: 28px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 28px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url('../img/form/day_radio_button.gif') no-repeat;
}
.jqTransformDayRadioWrapper label.active {
    background: url('../img/form/day_radio_button_selected.gif') no-repeat !important;
}
```

And Here is the HTML code generate by Cakephp Html Helper Form :

```
<div class="jqTransformDayRadioWrapper">
    <label for="EventReoccurringOnDay1">S</label>
    <input name="data[Event][reoccurring_on_day1]" type="text"  class="jqTransformDayRadioWrapper" value="0" id="EventReoccurringOnDay1" />

   <label for="EventReoccurringOnDay5">T</label>
    <input name="data[Event][reoccurring_on_day5]" type="text" checked="checked" class="jqTransformDayRadioWrapper" value="1" id="EventReoccurringOnDay5" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance:).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set your label to `display:block;` because labels are inline elements. And without display:block; your background image will not appear in IE 7.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i add the display:block; but still have the same issue: